# How to convert utf8 to text in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8, flutter-web, decoding

I want to convert special character utf8 value to it's text.

For example, if input is %20, the output will be whitespace
if input is %23, the output will be #

Comment: check [PercentCodec](https://pub.dev/documentation/convert/latest/convert/PercentCodec-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  var raw = 'Hello%20Bebop%23yahoo';
  var parsed = Uri.decodeComponent(raw);
  print(parsed);
}
```

Result:

```
Hello Bebop#yahoo
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you converting to an ASCCI like encoding. What function you are using for that result?
Try finding the encoding table to your %20 and %23 output, so you will see where you heading at the moment.